# English equivalent to "grandecito" in Spanish?

Tags: spanish, adjectives

What is the equivalent to "Grandecito" in English? At first it seems redundant because in English you cannot say, "big-small" or "small-big".  I have heard, "its biggie". I also have heard, "biggish", but the latter seems to be tied to more of a "kind of big" but not "big".

Comment: This question would be better suited for the English SE as a single word request (along with a brief explanation that grandecito is the adjective for large with a diminutive suffix)

Comment: You could say "*kind of a big deal*" (less jocularly: *kinda big*).

Comment: Is grandecito a real Spanish word? I cannot find it in any dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar is **largeish**:

> reasonably large, quite large. - [yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/largeish)

or indeed, as you've mentioned, **biggish**:

> somewhat big - [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biggish)

the -ish suffix has a softening effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand  "Grandecito," or if there is a single word.

But there are two techniques which I think come close:

.1. With people, *Hyperbole*:

> We say to a small boy "You're a **great big** boy now; you must ..." (be
>   careful with glasses/ be nice to your sister/ watch where you put your
>   feet/ etc)

.2. With objects it is more usual to use a child's word for big:

> "That's a **ginormous** sandwich you've got there; can you eat all that?"
>   "He gave her a ring with a **humungous** shiny stone."  "He was running
>   for dear life from a **flipping great** spider."

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [**whelming**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whelm). The dictionary definition makes this less severe than [**overwhelming**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overwhelm) and, because **overwhelm** is more commonly used, most native speakers will understand this as *big, but not so big*.

Comment: I would understand _whelming_ to mean something like ‘engulfing’. I would imagine water flooding over something. If it were used where in Spanish _grandecito_ would be used, I suspect I’d be most perplexed as to what the speaker was talking about.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Understood. I was trying to come up with a single-word synonym for "biggish" without any context to work with.