# Is there a way to contrast the words small/little and big to describe someone/something?

Tags: adjectives, irony

folks! How are you? :)

Well, here's my question: Is there a way to contrast the words **small/little** and **big** to describe the same person/thing?

I [found a thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254907/english-equivalent-to-grandecito-in-spanish) in which I think the question was not answered properly and the author's idea is the same that I have:

How to establish a paradox, in an ironic way, without being offensive, to say to a small man, he's a **little big** man?

Is that (little big) right for this purpose? Maybe **little great** man would be better in this case (not sure): little in terms of size and great in terms of heart, intelligence, responsibilities or something else.

Another exemple:

How do I tell to my friends that I learned a small thing in English but that that implies in a big difference to my life?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A big little man is different from a little big man, though... I'd also be careful drawing attention to someone's stature; whether they're taller, or shorter than average.

Answer (score 1):

One way (perhaps the simplest) to do this is to use a **comma** to separate the two elements, i.e., **little, big** man," Another way to express these paradoxical attributes is to use the conjunctive "but" to establish the contrast, as you have already done in your example, "I learned a small thing in English **but** that that implies in a big difference to my life."

Here, the conjunction "but" is used to contrast "*a big difference*" with "*a small thing*", and again, i.e., "*short of stature **but** great of girth*"

> [**but**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=hss&oq=but&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=but+definition&gs_l=hp..5.0l5j41.0.0.1.715595...........0.yjL1-D7bBcI&gws_rd=ssl)
>   *conjunction*: **1**. used to introduce something contrasting with what has already been mentioned.
>
> ***synonyms***: yet, nevertheless, nonetheless, even so, however, still, notwithstanding, despite that, in spite of that, for all that, all the same, just the same

(Google)

Comment: Thank you, @Little Eva. Is this the only way? For me it seems to be quite formal and a long way to express the idea. Using a figure of speech seems to add more flow to the sentence.